# How to retrieve the serial number of my NAS?

Tags: nas, remote-connection, wmi

I need to retrieve the serial number of a NAS.

From another PC, I wrote:

```
wmic /node:x.y.z.k bios get serialnumber
```

but I get this message:

```
ERROR:
Code = 0x800706ba
Description = The RPC server is unavailable.
Facility = Win32
```

I went to the server farm because I needed it quickly, but I'd like to know if I could solve it from a remote PC too.

Comment: Uh...won't this depend on the exact configuration of the NAS?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I don't know how this server is configured and I'm not a systemist. :) Could it be a firewall problem?

Comment: I mean, I'm not an expert, but it seems to me that this depends entirely on what kind of hardware and software is on the NAS.  They'll all report this differently.  (I wouldn't expect WMIC to be terrible useful with most NAS for one thing...)

Comment: WMIC is used to query Windows machines which I very much doubt the NAS is. They tend to use Unix/Linux operating systems and provide such information over SNMP or web interfaces.